# Emacs complaining with invalid function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I press `C-c c` with the following code on a buffer, Emacs complains with `Invalid function: (select-current-line)`. Why?

```
(defun select-current-line ()
  "Select the current line"
  (interactive)
  (end-of-line) ; move to end of line
  (set-mark (line-beginning-position)))

(defun my-isend ()
  (interactive)

  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
      (isend-send)

    ((select-current-line)
     (isend-send)))
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'my-isend)
```

Not that it matters, but for those interested [isend-send](https://github.com/emacsmirror/isend-mode) is defined here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? Calling `isend-send` without an active region already sends the current line, so I don't understand which behaviour you want to implement. Anyway, please feel free to open feature requests on [github](https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el)...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing a `progn` form to group statements together:

```lisp
(defun my-isend ()
  (interactive)

  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
      (isend-send)

    (progn
      (select-current-line)
      (isend-send))))
```

---

Without the `progn` form, `((select-current-line) (isend-send))` is interpreted as the `(select-current-line)` function applied to the result of calling `isend-send` without arguments. But `(select-current-line)` is not a valid function name. In other LISPs, such a construct could be valid if the return value of `select-current-line` was itself a function, which would then be applied to `(isend-send)`. But this is not the case of Emacs LISP and this would not do what you wanted to achieve anyway...