# Invalid function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp

I'm creating a function in Emacs Lisp that will read that whole buffer aloud if there is no active region. Otherwise, it reads the active region.

```
(defun speak-my-text () "Speaks text in buffer."
  (interactive)
(if (equal mark-active t)
   (
    (kill-ring-save (point-min) (point-max))
      (start-process-shell-command "speakbuffvar" nil 
        "bash -c \"killall espeak;xsel --clipboard|espeak -s 290\"")
           )
  (
    (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (start-process-shell-command "speakbuffvar" nil 
        "bash -c \"killall espeak;xsel --clipboard|espeak -s 290\"")
           )))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'speak-my-text)
```

I'm having trouble with the first line of the else clause:

```
(kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
```

When I define the function, bind it, and run, I get "Invalid function" and it points to that line. I'm running Linux Mint.

Comment: what are those lone open parens about? I think there should be progn after them

Comment: Also see duplicate-ish Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880783/emacs-complaining-with-invalid-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to phils' answer:

`mark-active` is not reliable in this context, as it might be
non-nil also if a region has no extend.

Function `region-active-p` would be usable, however depends on an
active `transient-mark-mode`, which might be unrelated - in most
cases it's useful and sufficient BTW.

Here is a example how to check for an valid region greater then
zero and surpassing `transient-mark-mode` issue:

```
(defun ar-region-active-p ()
  "Check for and existing region of some extend.

Don't mix up that question with transient-mark-mode "
  (interactive)
  (and (ignore-errors (region-beginning))(region-end) (< (region-beginning)(region-end))))
```

Based on this, your command might be written slightly differently:

```
(defun my-command-on-region ()
  "If a region of some extend exists, use on it.

Otherwise use whole buffer.

Doesn't require `transient-mark-mode' being active"
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg (or (and (ignore-errors (region-beginning))(region-end) (< (region-beginning)(region-end))(region-beginning))
         (point-min)))
   (end (or (and (ignore-errors (region-beginning))(region-end) (< (region-beginning)(region-end))(region-end))
         (point-max))))
    (DO-SOMETHING beg end)))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the alternate if setup and the pointer to progn.

Comment: While this answer has some good advice, it does not address the cause of the error. @phils has correctly identified the actual cause. It is important to remember that in lisp, the first element in an unquoted list is expected to be a function. In your code, you have a list where the first element is (kill-ring-save (region-begin) (region-end)). For this to execute correctly, it would need to return a function - or at least a symbol which resolves to a function. Generally, in lisp languages, you cannot just use () to nest expressions, you need something like prog etc.

Comment: @TimX Was in addition to phils answer - edited, to make that clear.

Comment: TimX: In elisp the first element *must* be a function symbol or a lambda expression; it cannot be an arbitrary expression *returning* a function.

Answer (score 4):

Use `C-h f progn` to evaluate multiple expressions sequentially.

You're currently attempting to *call a function* named `(kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))` and pass it the argument `(start-process-shell-command ...)`

Naturally, Emacs is telling you that `(kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))` is not the name of a function.